# Draw Shapes by Dragging

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d

I am newbie to Graphics Programming. I want to draw multiple shapes like Line, Rectangle and Oval by Dragging the mouse. I tried to accomplish this task but failed.

My Output Looks like this. 
[image]

Here is My Code :

```
public class JavaDraw extends JPanel implements ActionListener,
    MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

private JButton btnLine, btnRect, btnEclipse, btnPointer;
private DrawShape drawShape;
private Vector<Line2D.Double> vecLine;
private Vector<Rectangle2D.Double> vecRectangle;
private Vector<Ellipse2D.Double> vecEllipse;
private int left, right, top, bottom;
private Point startPoint, endPoint;

public JavaDraw(int width, int height) {
    this();
    setSize(width, height);
    setBackground(Color.orange);
}

public JavaDraw() {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    createControl();
    addControl();
    addListners();
}

private void createControl() {
    btnEclipse = new JButton("Eclipse");
    btnLine = new JButton("Line");
    btnRect = new JButton("Rectangle");
    btnPointer = new JButton("Pointer");

    vecEllipse = new Vector<>();
    vecLine = new Vector<>();
    vecRectangle = new Vector<>();

    startPoint = new Point();
    endPoint = new Point();
}

private void addControl() {

    add(btnLine);
    add(btnRect);
    add(btnEclipse);
    add(btnPointer);
}

private void addListners() {
    addActionListenerToControl();
    addMouseListenerToControl();
    addMouseMotionListenerToControl();
}

private void addActionListenerToControl() {
    btnEclipse.addActionListener(this);
    btnLine.addActionListener(this);
    btnPointer.addActionListener(this);
    btnRect.addActionListener(this);
}

private void addMouseListenerToControl() {
    addMouseListener(this);
}

private void addMouseMotionListenerToControl() {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

private void resizeShape(int x, int y) {
    endPoint.x = x;
    endPoint.y = y;
    updateBounds(startPoint, endPoint);
}

private void drawShape(Graphics g, boolean xor, DrawShape dm) {

    if (drawShape == DrawShape.DRAW_RECT)
        g.drawRect(left, top, Math.abs(left - right),
                Math.abs(top - bottom));
    else if (drawShape == DrawShape.DRAW_ELLIPSE)
        g.drawOval(left, top, Math.abs(left - right),
                Math.abs(top - bottom));
    else if (drawShape == DrawShape.DRAW_LINE)
        g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
}

void updateBounds(Point pt1, Point pt2) {
    left = (pt1.x < pt2.x) ? pt1.x : pt2.x;
    right = (pt1.x > pt2.x) ? pt1.x : pt2.x;
    top = (pt1.y < pt2.y) ? pt1.y : pt2.y;
    bottom = (pt1.y > pt2.y) ? pt1.y : pt2.y;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setXORMode(getBackground());

    if (e.getSource() == btnEclipse) {
        drawShape = DrawShape.DRAW_ELLIPSE;
    } else if (e.getSource() == btnLine) {
        drawShape = DrawShape.DRAW_LINE;
    } else if (e.getSource() == btnRect) {
        drawShape = DrawShape.DRAW_RECT;
    } 
    g.setPaintMode();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setXORMode(getBackground());

    resizeShape(e.getX(), e.getY());
    drawShape(g, true, drawShape);

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    startPoint = e.getPoint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

}

enum DrawShape {
    DRAW_LINE, DRAW_RECT, DRAW_ELLIPSE
}
```

But if i Call `repaint()` method then previously drawn shapes get disappears.

Pls help me with it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getGrapchic()`. You need to learn the basics of custom painting. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).  Basically what you want to do is override `paintComponent` and do your painting there.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    // draw here.
}
```

When ever you `repaint()` the panel, the `paintComponent` will be implicitly called. So you could do something like

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (Rectangle2D rect: rectangles) {
        g2.fill(rect);
    }
}
```

You could then, for instance, add a new `Rectangle2D` object to the `List<Rectangle2D> rectagles`, and there would be another rectangle drawn on the canvas.

Also you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23183787/2587435), which shows how you can create the shape by dragging the mouse

[image]

The code in the example only uses one rectangle, but you could easily modify it to draw a `List` of rectangles. And every time the mouse is pressed, it will add a new rectangle to the list, while still allowing you to drag the mouse to size the current rectangle obtained from the mouse press. Examine the link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. Please can you help me for performing further graphics operation on it.

Comment: Just post another specific question on SO, showing what you have so far, and what exactly you need accomplished. I'll have a look at it.